# Deriving *halachah* from the books of the Prophets

Tags: halacha, halacha-theory, navi-prophets

The Talmud in multiple places uses the principle *divrei Torah midivrei kabbalah lo yalfinan*, which usually is interpreted to mean that *halachah* cannot be derived from the words of the Prophets, and if one needs a source, then only a source from the Pentateuch can be used.

For example, in the beginning of *Bava Kamma*, the Talmud uses this principle to question classification of goring based on a verse from the Book of Kings (and answers that it's not being used as a *halachah* but as a dictionary, which is permissible).

However, in multiple other places, the Talmud does exactly the opposite. In particular the first *mishnah* in [tractate **Shabbos**, chapter 9](http://www.emishnah.com/PDFs/Shabbat%209.pdf), Rabbi Akiva clearly derives what seems like an *issur mideoraysa* from a verse in Yishayahu 30:32, drawing an equivalence between an idol and a menstruant.

Can someone please help me understand when this principle is, and is not, to be used -- what are the boundaries of applying this correctly? Thank you very much.

Comment: Why do you think R Akiva is speaking about a Deorayta? Rambam (Avot HaTumah 6) doesn't learn that way: טומאת עבודה זרה, מדברי סופרים; ויש לה רמז מן התורה, "הסירו את אלוהי הנכר, אשר בתוככם, והיטהרו . . ." (בראשית לה,ב).  ארבעה אבות הטומאה יש בה--עבודה זרה עצמה, ומשמשיה, ותקרובת שלה, ויין שנתנסך לה; וטומאת כולן, מדבריהם Rabbenu Chananel to your Mishna also calls it an Asmakhta.

Comment: For me, there's no way of telling if a certain Limud is THE source or just an Asmachtah fora Halachah, see https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/94517/in-the-talmud-is-there-a-way-to-distinguish-when-a-verse-is-brought-as-%D7%9E%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%A8-or-%D7%90 And it does not matter if it's from Prophets or Torah verses.

Comment: Hey, I'm currently studying this Gemara. +1

Comment: This is a good question. In particular, a significant number of halachot of *tefillah* are derived from Shlomo Hamelech's actions and expressions during the dedication of the 1st Bet Hamikdash. It seems, apparently, that we do have many halachot derived from Nevi'im, at least.

Comment: We can't learn something *new* from the prophets because they weren't meant to be mechadesh anything(in terms of Torah law); but we can learn from the prophets to find the original meaning of a Torah law. We do derive a lot of Rabbinic law from the prophets(like tefila and Chana). There's a sugya about this subject(don't recall where exactly). See here for more: http://dafyomi.co.il/discuss_daf.php?gid=14&sid=20&daf=14&n=1

Comment: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=19611&st=&pgnum=71

Comment: @wfb link does not work

Comment: @gt6989b works for me. try http://hebrewbooks.org/19611 p. 71

Comment: @wfb Error 1005: Access Denied

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Maharatz Chajes (Maamar Torat Nevi'im) addresses this question at length and explains that what appears in Nevi'im is only derabbanan (in the following chapter of this treatise, he addresses the counterexamples):

> דמצינו בשלשה פעמים בש"ס (חגיגה י"א ע"ב, ב"ק ב' ע"ב, ונדה כ"ג ע"א)
>   דדברי תורה מדברי קבלה לא ילפינן, והטעם כיון דמצות התורה עומדים לדורות
>   בלי הפסק, ותורת הנביאים אינם רק לשעה, דאם באו ללמד ולהורות דינים
>   לדורות אין שומעין להם, וכמו דקי"ל (מנחות י"ט ע"ב) ושם (נ"ו ע"ב)
>   (סנהדרין ט"ו ע"ב) דדורות משעה לא ילפינן...וזה נמי הטעם דד"ת מד"ק לא ילפינן משום דד"ק אינם רק
>   לשעה ואין למדין דורות משעה.
>
> ולפ"ז נראה בהשקפה ראשונה, דכל הני דינים והלכות הרבות אשר למדו חז"ל
>   מדברי נביאים, הנה משפט כל אלו ההלכות אינם רק כשאר תקנות וסייגי חכמים,
>   שהם רק משום גדר ומשמרת לדברי תורה, אבל אין אזהרתם שוה לדברי תורה,
>   ויהיה להם כל חומר דין תורה הן להחמיר בספיקם והן לענוש העובר במלקות
>   ומיתה, ובאמת מצינו כן בש"ס אשר חז"ל השוו דינים היוצאים מד"ק רק כדרבנן,
>   (פסחים י"ד ע"א) אמר רבא דמן התורה אין אוכל מטמא אוכל, וכתב רש"י א"כ כל
>   דברי חגי שאמר היגע איש בשר קודש בבגדו וכו' המה רק מדרבנן, וכן שבות
>   דשבת אף ע"ג דכתיב והצורים ישבו בה מביאים דאג וכל מכר, ונאמר שמה ומנערי
>   העמדתי אשר לא יבא משא ביום השבת [נחמיה י"ג, ט"ז-י"ט], ומ"מ אמרינן (שבת
>   קכ"ג ע"ב) משנה זו בימי נחמיה בן חכליה נישנית התירו וחזרו והתירו, וכן
>   קי"ל באמת דשבות דמקח וממכר אינו רק מדרבנן, וכן קי"ל מעשר אילן וירק
>   אינם רק מדרבנן ואע"ג דכתיב בקרא, וכפרוץ הדבר הרבו בני ישראל ראשית דגן
>   ותירוש לרוב [דה"ב ל"א, ה'], ואמר אביי לאתויי פירות אילן וירק (נדרים
>   נ"ה ע"א) ועי' רש"י והר"ן שמה ועי' ג"כ רש"י ותוס' (מכות כ"ג ע"ב) לענין
>   הסכמת ב"ד של מעלה בהבאת מעשר פי' דקאי על תקנות יחזקי', **ועיין נמי רש"י
>   (שבת פ"ג ע"ב) לענין טומאת ע"ז דמסיק הש"ס דאינו רק מדבריהם, ואע"ג
>   דילפינן בהיקש תזרם כמו דוה דאתקש לנדה וכן כתי' וישלך עפרה אל קבר בני
>   העם מה מת מטמא אף ע"ז נמי כ' רש"י שם דאינו רק אסמכתא משום דכל הני
>   היקשות דברי קבלה נינהו,** ועיין תוס' (ע"ז כ"ב ע"ב) ד"ה תיפוק לי' דכ'
>   כיון דאבילות אין לו סמך בד"ת רק בקבלה הקלו בו, ועי' תוספות (קידושין ט'
>   ע"א) ד"ה הלכתא דכ' כיון דאין למוד זה רק מד"ק לא שייך להקשות הלכתא
>   למ"ל.

The Ramban in Sefer Ha-Mitzvot (shoresh 2) explains that since Nevi'im cannot create new laws, the Gemara will sometimes say הא מקמי דאתא יחזקאל מאן אמרה? אלא גמרא גמיר לה ואתא יחזקאל ואסמכה אקרא. In these cases, too, the Navi is not creating a new law, but is writing down what was until then an oral tradition; these laws would be מדאורייתא.

Answer (score -1):

The Talmud already assumes the halacha to be true (as derived from the Oral tradition), and never ever derives the source from a Pasuk.  The Pasuk is used to show where in the Torah this Oral Tradition/Halacha maybe found, but it is not the source.  The source of derivation is our Oral Tradition.

Since every Oral Torah statement can be matched up in the Torah itself, you cannot infer any halacha from Divrei Kabbalah.

However, what you can do is show that this is what was practiced and held to be the case from Divrei Kabbalah.