# Can halacha be derived from gematria?

Tags: halacha-theory, gematria-numerology, maseches-nazir

The Talmud says:

Mishnah: A Nazirite vow of unspecified duration [remains in force] thirty days.  Gemara: From where is this rule derived? Rabbi Mattena said: The text reads: He shall be [yihyeh] holy, and the numerical value of the word "yihyeh" is thirty. [Nazir 5a]

I thought we were not allowed to derive halacha from gematria.  Are we?

(As an aside, wouldn't the gematria of "holy" be more appropriate?)

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/11553/759

Comment: @DoubleAA -- Yes, There are other examples.  But I am looking for a statement, "No, we may not derive halacha from gematria".  (Gematria is only a mnemonic device.)  Is there such a thing?

Comment: Consider https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/44758/759

Comment: @DoubleAA -- Is there a statement anywhere that an asmakhta is a known and applied oral law from long, long ago, but whose derivation from Torah has been lost, so the gematria is used just as a mnemonic, not a proof?

Answer (score 2):

Your motivating example is not necessarily a case of “deriving” *halachah* from *gematria*.

Rambam writes in is [Commentary to Nazir 1:3](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Rambam_on_Mishnah_Nazir.1.3?lang=he) that the thirty-day *nazir* rule is a received tradition, which the Rabbis supported using the *gematria* as a hint.

I speculate that Rambam says this as he is loathe to view a *gematria* as the primary source for this *halachah*. This would suggest that he is of the opinion that one cannot straightforwardly derive laws from *gematria*.

Comment: I'm not sure this answers the question

Comment: Edited to more directly answer the question. (Admittedly it’s now somewhat more speculative...)

Answer (score 0):

Halachah is ruled, not *necessarily* derived. It can be ruled in two ways:

- either by learning the source and deriving from it, as you mentioned,
- or by ruling it first and making an Asmachtah afterward (by relying on a verse).

This is very common with the Gemmarah and it is impossible to distinguish between them. I posted [a question about this problem](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/94517/in-the-talmud-is-there-a-way-to-distinguish-when-a-verse-is-brought-as-%D7%9E%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%A8-or-%D7%90).

Your question is a good example of an Asmachtah for a Halachah - something that merely strengthens the claim.

Comment: Isn’t an asmachta usually a din derabbanan backed up with a hint from a pasuk? I’m pretty sure this is deoraita...

Comment: @JoelK As we have no tools for judging a Halachah objectively, "anything goes" - whatever sounds reasonable proves your point. That's called אסמכתא.

Comment: @Al Berko -- OK, so it's an asmakhtah, but ARE we allowed to learn halacha from gematria?  Any sources that directly address this question?

Comment: There are no rules of how to rule Halochos. Our motto is **כל דאלים גבר - everything goes**. He can say "Cause I said so" - won't it suffice? BTW a sage does not have to give you his reasoning at all, maybe you won't understand, maybe you'll misunderstand and think it's BS. Sometimes he feels it's true but can't find a good supporting claim.

Comment: The Gemara asked: "From where is this rule derived?, not "What is the rule?".  If an answer is given (and it is), must we assume THAT is the source?

Comment: @AlBerko I think that’s a little cynical. “Cause I said so” would not seem to fall into one of Rambam’s [five sources of halachot](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Rambam_Introduction_to_the_Mishnah.14?lang=bi).

Comment: @JoelK Have you talked to some Gdoylim in private? That's exactly what they say. אם הרב דומה למלאך צבאות ה' שמע בקולו. He does not need to explain himself - see what I commented to Maurice.

Comment: @AlBerko The quote is יבקשו תורה מפיהו, not שמע בקולו. You have to seek torah from him. Pronouncements *ex cathedra* are part of another religion.

Comment: @JoelK I've got an impression that some people are interested in plain arguing more than finding the truth.