# Why is there no differentiation between drashos and asmachtos in shaas?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, history, talmud-gemara

Similar to [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/94517/15457) quesion, I have been bothered for a while now with the following question: How is it that the Talmud was written with no indication at all between drashos gemuros and asmachtos?

Comment: May I ask why you expect such an indication to exist?

Comment: @robev because the ramifications are big.